# Can't apt-get update

Tags: 14.04, apt, xterm

This is what x-term says:

```
sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for branja: 
sudo: apt-get: command not found
```

How can I fix it? `apt-get -f install` doesn't work either.

edit: I've installed apt via dpkg -i and it worked like a charm. Tnx guys.

Comment: That should never happen... what's changed? Anything else not working? Any results from `ls -la /usr/bin/apt*`

Comment: Problem with the PATH variable? What does `echo $PATH` say?

Answer (score 0):

Here the steps to solve it:

1. Open up Ubuntu Software Center.
2. Type apt in the search bar.
3. You would get "Commandline package manager" in the search results.

Now, go ahead and install it.

If the above steps failed working, you could download apt deb package from the following site. http://en.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/. In the site, both x86 and x64 versions are available. Once you have downloaded the deb package, install it by typing `sudo dpkg -i {deb_filename}` in the terminal.

Note: Replace the {deb_filename} with the downloaded deb filename in the command.

Comment: Now that's kind of an paradox since the Ubuntu Software Center uses APT under the hood. ;) If for some reason APT isn't installed, than the USC will also fail to install that package.